# copy pointer value c++

Tags: c++, buffer, variable-assignment, arrays

I have a unsigned c++ char buffer

```
unsigned char* pBuffer =  new unsigned char [1024];
```

I want to save the `pBuffer` pointer in the first few bytes of the newly allocated buffer by using an assignement rather than memcpy- ie

```
*(unsigned char*) &pBuffer[0] = pBuffer;
```

I am not able to get the sytax right. Appreciate help with the correct syntax for doing this.

Visual Studio 2010

Comment: use std::vector< std::vector<unsigned char> >.

Comment: Which compiler are you using ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why you would want to do this, but I can think of a few oddball reasons, so:

```
reinterpret_cast<unsigned char**>(pBuffer)[0] = pBuffer;
```

You want the compiler to reinterpret the pointer as a `unsigned char**`, and store the value of `pBuffer` in the 0-index slot.

You said you're indexing a "linked list" with multiple pBuffers.  In that case, you *should not use* reinterpret_cast.  Instead:

```
struct node {
     node* prev;
     std::unique_ptr<node> next;
     unsigned char buffer[1024];
     node(node* prev_) : prev(prev_) {}
};

std::unique_ptr<node> list(new node(nullptr)); //tada
```

Comment: that worked, Thank you. I am trying to make a custom "link list" with multiple pBuffers.

Comment: @user85917: That is _not_ one of the cases to use `reinterpret_cast`.  I added more info to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
*((unsigned char**) pBuffer) = pBuffer;
```

It casts the `pBuffer` pointer to a pointer to a pointer to a char, and then dereferences that to make it a pointer to a char that is then assigned the `pBuffer` pointer.

It might be easier to understand if we write it like this:

```
unsigned char **ppBuffer = &pBuffer;
*ppBuffer = pbuffer;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are doing this, but this works with my `g++` compiler:

```
*(unsigned char**)pBuffer=pBuffer;
```